# Query in command must target single shard key

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I have an array of document ids using which I wish to delete the documents with the given id. The document id is also the shard key of the document. So I provided the following query for `model.deleteMany(query)`

query:
`{ doc_id: { '$in': [ 'docid1', 'docid2' ] } }`

I still get the error **Query in command must target single shard key**.
Is it possible to overcome this without looping through the array and deleting the docs one by one?

Answer (score 0):

By matching any document in the collection with the `_id` field, you can make a query or delete command:

```
db.collection.deleteMany({ _id: { $exists: true }})
```

During the specification of the schema model in the code, a Shard Key (Partition Key) must be specified. We may execute operations such as save, update, and delete once it is provided

```
const mySchema = new Schema({
    requestId: { type: String, required: true },
    data: String,
    documents: [{ docId: String, name: String, attachedBy: String }],
    updatedBy: {
        type: {
            name: { type: String, required: true },
            email: { type: String, required: true },
        }, required: true
    },
    createdDate: { type: Date, required: true },
    updatedDate: { type: Date },
}, { shardKey: { requestId: 1 } }
);
```